# PHP CRUD returns true but doesnt add to database

Tags: php, crud

I guess I'm missing something here. I'm developing a CRUD in PHP so I can do my functions easily.
It seems to work, but it doesn't add anything to database (I don't have any mysqli errors).

What I'm missing here?

Usage of my function:

```
        if(crud_insert($mysqli, 'users', $args) == true){
            $response["icon"] = "fa fa-check";
            $response["title"] = "Success";
            $response["status"] = "success";
            $response["message"] = $response["message"] . "Your account have been created with success.<br/>";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
            $response["status"] = "danger";
            $response["message"] = $response["message"] . "There was a problem creating your account. Please try again later.<br/>";
            echo json_encode($response);

        }
```

My crud_insert function:

```
function crud_insert($conn, $table, $data) {
    $sql = create_insert_query($table, array_keys($data));
    if(prepared_query($conn, $sql, array_values($data))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

My create_insert_query function:

```
function create_insert_query($table, $keys){
    $keys = array_map('escape_mysql_identifier', $keys);
    $fields = implode(",", $keys);
    $table = escape_mysql_identifier($table);
    $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
    return "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
}
```

My prepared_query:

```
function prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types = ""){
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    } else {
        $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
        error_log($error);
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to call crud_insert in table 'users' with $args var that contains something like:

```
$args["username"] = "123";
$args["password"] = "mypassword";
```

Just to ensure, all fields exist in the database (username, password, etc), otherwise, I would get Unknown column error.

Can someone guide me please? Thanks

Comment: There are lots you can do to check - does `$sql` generate OK (have you tried it in PHPMyAdmin with some values in).  Does `$stmt->execute()` actually succeed?

Comment: Check! Thanks for pointing me. The problem I was not fullfying some columns in database so there was an error as some fields aren't properly configured. Thanks!